# Informatica_date_sequencing

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to create an automated workflow which takes date as an input in descending order?
At a one it should take single date and sync all those records for that particular date.

Next time it should take another date.

Comment: can you give some examples - like input data and expected output ? how does it matter if it processes without order? It works like  a SQL - it processes all rows together - not one at a time.

Comment: Store the date in some DB or a control file. Update the value by substracting one day as the last step of the workflow.